# Simple Select SQL Query Running Infinitely on a SQL Server table NOT having large data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to do a select query on a SQL Server table which DOES NOT have large data but the query is running infinitely, every time I have to cancel it after waiting for 5-8 mins. Table only has about 3000 records.

Table structure as below:

```
Begin Try
CREATE TABLE tbl_Random
(
    ID                  int           NULL,
    Cust_Id             smallint      NULL,
    Mbr_Id              int           NULL,
    Appl_Id             int           NULL,
    Code                varchar(20)   NULL,
    Req_Date            datetime      NULL,
    Apd                 char(1)       NULL DEFAULT 'N',
    Apd_By              varchar(20)   NULL,
    Apd_Date            datetime      NULL,
    Status              varchar(20)   NULL,
    Sent                char(1)       NULL DEFAULT 'N',
    Sent_Date           datetime      NULL,
    Post_Date           datetime      NULL,
    Delt_Flag           char(1)       NULL DEFAULT 'N',
    Delt_By             varchar(5)    NULL,
    Delt_Date           datetime      NULL,
    Delt_Reason         varchar(100)  NULL,
    Created_By          varchar(100)  NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_USER,
    Created_On          datetime      NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    Updated_By          varchar(100)  NULL,
    Updated_On          datetime      NULL,
    Notes               nvarchar(255) NULL
); 
End Try
Begin Catch
    Print Error_Message();
End Catch
```

When I do run the below queries, it brings up the result in less then a second

```
Select Top 1000 * from tbl_Random
```

```
Select Top 2000 * from tbl_Random
```

```
Select Top 2500 * from tbl_Random
```

But when I do

```
Select Top 3000 * from tbl_Random
```

it loads the tabular data till 2945 rows quickly in a second but then keeps executing infinitely.

Also the below query keeps executing infinitely with no Result output.

```
Select Top 1 * from tbl_Random Order By ID Desc
```

So I think something wrong with the bottom rows, anything I can do to fix this please?

Using SQL Server Management Studio 18.

Comment: Check whether another process has a lock on the table or a row in the table.

Comment: @DaleK : Thanks but how to check that, sorry i am new to SQL and databases so if you could guide me the best :)

Comment: There are loads of resources out there to help with that - your favourite search engine will guide you.

Comment: FYI, *"Using SQL Server Management Studio 18."* Doesn't tell us anything. SSMS is just an IDE; it's like telling us you're using Visual Studio 2019 when asked what version of .Net you're using.

Comment: I don't think anything is wrong with the "bottom" rows (though a table is an unordered bag of rows *and* you didn't ask for top in any specific order anyway). I think more likely you are hitting a resource limitation as SSMS tries to use your local workstation (how much memory do you have?) to render a grid with 66,000 cells. What happens if you use `results to text` instead? Is your goal really to return _that much data_ to a grid in SSMS? Why? Shouldn't you be testing how your application retrieves and renders 66,000 values (or, more likely, uses pagination to show _a lot less_ at a time)?

Comment: ^ There's a reason Google shows you 10 results at a time instead of 3,000.

Comment: Your table is a HEAP - try adding a clustered index and defining a primary key.

Comment: what happens when you execute: select * from table? does this return without issue?

Comment: `DBCC OPENTRAN` should give you useful info, if someone is locking up the table. By the way `Begin Catch Print Error_Message(); End Catch` is the silliest catch block I've ever seen. You can only view the `PRINT` message in SSMS, which would show the error anyway. So why use try catch at all?

Comment: Run ```SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED``` before your query to ignore locks on data. Then to rule out network/SSSMS issues, try running ```SELECT TOP(3000) * INTO #temp FROM tbl_Random``` This will save off your results to a temp table so nothing ever leaves the server. Also are you sure tbl_random is a table and not a view?